# Get user.home directory in Windows 11 using Java or Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, directory

I am running Android Studio (Arctic Fox) on a Windows 11 platform. I need to save an app's settings in the folder: C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local.
My problem is when I try to build a path to that folder using System.getProperty("user.home") both Java and Kotlin return a blank (empty string). How can I get a string showing the path to the user folder? Please help!

Comment: Do you run `System.getProperty("user.home")` in your android app? Android devices (normally) don't have users.

Comment: Ah! That will explain it.

Comment: I got confused between Windows features and Android features. :-)

Comment: All the code in the `src` folder is executed in Android.